# Plotly.js Axis Click/Drag Event

Tags: javascript, plotly, axis

I have multiple y-axis in a line chart. Only the last y-axis related grid lines are shown by default. If the user clicks on any other y-axis, grid lines for that y-axis should be shown. But I am unable to find any event in plotly.js which triggers when the axis is clicked or dragged.

Comment: Please add some code snippet

Comment: Can't you use [Legend Click Events](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#legend-click-events) to handle that?

Comment: @MaartenPeels : If the user clicks on legend, the default functionality of toggling the visibility of graph is being used. I dont want that to change the gridcolor of the axis.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment yet. Here's a rather hacky way of registering clicks on yaxis labels. Not sure if that's helpful.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3],
  y: [40, 50, 60],
  name: 'yaxis data',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4],
  y: [4, 5, 6],
  name: 'yaxis2 data',
  yaxis: 'y2',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Double Y Axis Example',
  yaxis: {title: 'yaxis title'},
  yaxis2: {
    title: 'yaxis2 title',
    titlefont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'},
    tickfont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'},
    overlaying: 'y',
    side: 'right'
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('chart', data, layout);

var myPlot = document.getElementById('chart');
myPlot.on('plotly_afterplot', function(){
    Plotly.d3.selectAll(".nsdrag.drag.cursor-ns-resize")
          .on("click", function() {
              var target = Plotly.d3.event.target;
              console.log('clicked on', target.dataset.subplot);
          });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plotly.js/1.49.5/plotly.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart">
</div>
```